# avr assembler: #define vs .equ, is it the same?

Tags: assembly, definition, avr

Is the avr-c command

```
#define baudrate 9600
```

the same like the avr-asm command

```
.equ BAUD  = 9600
```

??

Comment: one is a C directive the other is an assembly language direction.  Once you pollute your assembly language with C directives and require a C preprocessor it really isnt assembly language anymore it is a hybrid.  If you are going to do that you might as well just go all the way to inline assembly...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to official [guide](http://www.atmel.com/Images/doc1022.pdf) (see 4.5.9):

> The EQU directive assigns a value to a label. This label can then be used in later
>   expressions. A label assigned to a value by the EQU directive is a constant and can not
>   be changed or redefined.

`equ` is very similar to C-language `#define` directive, but there is one difference: `equ` can't be redefined.